# R shiny image and removing black dot

Tags: shiny

When using R shiny and adding an image, I get a black dot appearing on the dashboard on the upper left hand corner. I've tried using padding but I still can't remove it? I paste below a reproducible example and also add a screenshot[image]

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$li(div(img(src = 'iris.jpg'),align = "right"
  )))
server <- function(input, output) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

The dot you see is the dot from the "li" element. "li" is used to make lists, with dots or squares at the beginning. Just remove `tags$li` and the dot won't be there anymore

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  div(img(src = 'iris.jpg'),align = "right"
  ))
server <- function(input, output) {}
```